# How to use jq to iterate through Nagios JSON

Tags: json, nagios, jq

I'm trying to figure out how to parse the following JSON without having to explicitly indicate the array index in multiple commands.  I just need to associate the hostgroup on a single line with all of the host information.

```
{
  "data": {
    "selectors": {
    },
    "hostgroups": [
      {
        "name": "ATL",
        "hosts": [
          {
            "name": "ATL-SERVER1",
            "time_up": 2496629,
            "time_down": 8970,
            "time_unreachable": 0,
            "scheduled_time_up": 0,
            "scheduled_time_down": 0,
            "scheduled_time_unreachable": 0,
            "time_indeterminate_nodata": 0,
            "time_indeterminate_notrunning": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "ATL-SERVER2",
            "time_up": 2505525,
            "time_down": 74,
            "time_unreachable": 0,
            "scheduled_time_up": 0,
            "scheduled_time_down": 0,
            "scheduled_time_unreachable": 0,
            "time_indeterminate_nodata": 0,
            "time_indeterminate_notrunning": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "LAX",
        "hosts": [
          {
            "name": "LAX-SERVER1",
            "time_up": 2505599,
            "time_down": 0,
            "time_unreachable": 0,
            "scheduled_time_up": 0,
            "scheduled_time_down": 0,
            "scheduled_time_unreachable": 0,
            "time_indeterminate_nodata": 0,
            "time_indeterminate_notrunning": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "LAX-SERVER2",
            "time_up": 2505599,
            "time_down": 0,
            "time_unreachable": 0,
            "scheduled_time_up": 0,
            "scheduled_time_down": 0,
            "scheduled_time_unreachable": 0,
            "time_indeterminate_nodata": 0,
            "time_indeterminate_notrunning": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The following commands will get me what I need:

```
.data.hostgroups[0].name as $Group | {$Group} + .data.hostgroups[0].hosts[] | [.Group, .name, .time_up, .time_down, .time_unreachable, .scheduled_time_up, .scheduled_time_down, .scheduled_time_unreachable, .time_indeterminate_nodata, .time_indeterminate_notrunning] | @csv
.data.hostgroups[1].name as $Group | {$Group} + .data.hostgroups[1].hosts[] | [.Group, .name, .time_up, .time_down, .time_unreachable, .scheduled_time_up, .scheduled_time_down, .scheduled_time_unreachable, .time_indeterminate_nodata, .time_indeterminate_notrunning] | @csv
```

But I've been trying to figure out how to do this in one line.  I have 20 hostgroups, so this is 20 commands in my script.

All of the comparable examples I've found seem to apply to only pulling a single field out of the array (in my example it is host[]). For example, this will work fine:

```
map(.data.hostgroups | map({Group: .name, Host: .hosts[].name} | [.Group, .Host])) | add[] | @csv
```

And the output is:

```
"ATL","ATL-SERVER1"
"ATL","ATL-SERVER2"
"LAX","LAX-SERVER1"
"LAX","LAX-SERVER2"
```

But when I add an additional field in, for example:

```
map(.data.hostgroups | map({Group: .name, Host: .hosts[].name, Uptime: .hosts[].time_up} | [.Group, .Host, .Uptime])) | add[] | @csv
```

The output is:

```
"ATL","ATL-SERVER1",2496629
"ATL","ATL-SERVER1",2505525
"ATL","ATL-SERVER2",2496629
"ATL","ATL-SERVER2",2505525
"LAX","LAX-SERVER1",2505599
"LAX","LAX-SERVER1",2505599
"LAX","LAX-SERVER2",2505599
"LAX","LAX-SERVER2",2505599
```

For every field I add, it basically multiplies them together. And I'm pretty sure I understand why that is, but I'm still trying to figure out how to one line this while avoiding the problem of exponentially combining the results.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat extract.jq
.data.hostgroups[]
| .name as $Group
| .hosts[]
| [$Group, .name, .time_up, .time_down, .time_unreachable,
   .scheduled_time_up, .scheduled_time_down, 
   .scheduled_time_unreachable, .time_indeterminate_nodata, 
   .time_indeterminate_notrunning]
| @csv


$ jq -r -f extract.jq in.json
"ATL","ATL-SERVER1",2496629,8970,0,0,0,0,0,0
"ATL","ATL-SERVER2",2505525,74,0,0,0,0,0,0
"LAX","LAX-SERVER1",2505599,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
"LAX","LAX-SERVER2",2505599,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked for me, and I understand why this is necessary now.  I see how | .host[] is ran through properly, and I understand how the loop works now. Thanks so much!